# CodeCommit cross account deploys with CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I'm struggling with a glass of water...

I'm trying to implement cross-account deployments. Currently, I have four accounts: DevOps, Dev, Prod, and QA. All the repositories are on the DevOps account, and each CodeBuild execution deploys a new image on an EKS cluster (in Dev/QA/Prod). Currently, the pipeline is executed inside the VPC of the EKS cluster and has access to the EKS cluster's security group. I'm trying to follow this architecture: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/use-aws-codecommit-and-aws-codepipeline-to-deploy-a-ci-cd-pipeline-in-multiple-aws-accounts.html, but the pipeline always fails because it can't find the source repository (which is in the DevOps account) since CodePipeline keeps looking in its same account. I tried placing a CodeCommit ARN (it doesn't have any, but...) in the name field, and with a service role directly from the DevOps account. KMS key on devops account is also configured and im using it on the pipeline.

Sadly, changing to Bitbucket, GitHub, or GitLab is not an option.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 IAM Roles in plays in context of AWS CodePipeline. These IAM Roles  dictates cross-account deployment:

1. Pipeline IAM Role https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html#cfn-codepipeline-pipeline-rolearn - this role should be able to assume a target account role (below). Means it should have an sts:AssumeRole permission attached
2. Target account IAM Role (Action declaration role) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_ActionDeclaration.html (check roleArn). This role should have access to CodeCommit and Trust the account where CodePipeline is located.
3. Some actions (e.g. Deploy) might have a 3rd IAM Role (action configuration role) - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html (check Role name or RoleArn)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry i tried that but there isnt any option in code pipeline to select as source the code commit repo of the devops account. Even if the code pipeline role has permissions to assume a role in devops account  with administrator access. I just moved all the pipelines to devops account and during the execution of my build step (code-build) i assumed a role in DEV/QA/PROD that allows me to deploy on the EKS cluster

Comment: You provide a CodeCommit repo name. Which account to use is defined by the RoleArn you provide in Source action declaration. If this IAM Role is from different AWS account - Pipeline will get sources from that other account. 
You just need to make sure that overall IAM Role you use as service role for you pipeline can assume IAM Role you are using for action declaration.

Comment: if i do that it just fails because it couldnt find the role in the dev account (the role and the pipeline are both from devops account). The same thing happens if you try to create a pipeline manually, choose "select an existing service role" and put a role from another account (even if that role have permissions for code pipeline and dev accounts to assume it)